# Python pass paremeters that come before function

Tags: python, function

I want it to be similar to these two functions:

```
split()
join()
```

The key parts of those functions is that it is not like:

```
split('test:test2', ':')
```

But however:

```
'test:test2'.split(:)
'1'.join[2,3]
```

How can I make a function like, for example:

```
'hello'.say()
```

And the output be:

```
hello
```

(I am pretty new to python)
Also if you know how to make something with a colon e.g.:

```
say():
    'hello'
    'hi'
```

If the second and maybe first one is impossible, sorry, I am new.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `print()`?

Comment: Yes, that is just an example, I need it for other reasons.

Comment: Ok i got this: s('test').say()

Comment: But I dont think it is possible to modify string class at all? Is it?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry. I'm fairly new to python myself.